# JP60081025(A), Japanese version of FR2553560, Why was it lapsed in April 1997?

Tags: licence

The Japanese version JP60081025(A) of France patent FR2553560 has been lapsed in 1997 April before the lapse of the France version in 1998. I suspect that the France Areva contracted with assignee JAERI for that valuable patent. I would like to know the specifics of the Japanese patent as the inventor.

Comment: According to the recent google patent information, the Japanese version is expired-lifetime, on the other hand France version is expired in 1998 when it is before 6 years  to the lifetime

Comment: I have to know the detail of the lapse of France version FR2553560 rather than the Japanese version because the Japanese version was maintained to the lifetime.

Comment: As both patents are expired and would be even if the French version hadn’t had lapsed, is this no more than an academic exercise? Whether or not to allow a patent to lapse is a business decision. The business doesn’t have to explain its decision to the patent office. There is no way anyone here can answer the question why that decision was made with respect to the French patent.

Comment: The assignee and Areva are both owned by Japan  and France goverments respectivily. So that this problem may not be always a business.

Comment: My point is no one here can help you figure out why the French patent was allowed to lapse. As for this question, the part about the French patent and Areva is irrelevant. What you should be asking is how to search the Japanese Patent Office site to get information about the Japanese patent. That is about all we can help you with. Sorry.

Comment: I have already contacted with Japanese patent office concerning this problem. They only showed that the patent was lapsed in 1997 due to the nonpayment of patent fee. That is different from the record of Google patent where the patent was maintained to the lifetime 2003.

Comment: Google Patents is not perfect.

Comment: Did you get the information on the Japanese patent in Google patent or other site ?

Comment: I just looked at it in Google Patent which doesn't provide much information. I don't know how to use the Japanese patent office's site. Google Patents is fast and easy, but does sometimes have mistakes and isn't official in any way.